# setting up rails/sqlite3 on OSX 10.5.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I'm trying to get get going on a rails tutorial and get get past the installation. I'm a newbie.

1 . ran "`rails new app1`." - The app is created but bundler fails (looks like it is run as part of the `rails new` command

> An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5),

1. changed the gemfile to explicitly call for `"gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'` (this is the most recent version that works on osx 10.5)"
2. ran "bundle install" - success
3. try to view the default app and see the error

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

looked in config/database.yml. It says "`database: db/development.sqlite3`"

looked in db/ - no database here.  -    -    *Is a db supposed to be created during `rails new`?*

Tried running `rake db:migrate`  - get

> "rake aborted!
>   : Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)"

Tried running that command, got

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, activerecord-spatialite-adapter, activerecord-n
ulldb-adapter, activerecord-dbslayer-adapter
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Anybody have an idea what I need to do?
OSX 10.5.8 (leopard)
rails 3.2.0
ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Well that last part is a bit hairy sounding, but to get your database sorted you want:

```
rake db:setup
```

...not migration, to create the database.

```
rake -T | grep db
```

...shows you the options, for future reference. Let's see what happens after that :)